# How do I find the location of WebLogic's servlet.jar programatically (on Windows)

Tags: servlets, websphere, weblogic

In our sample code installer we want to find the location of WebLogic's servlet.jar file (if it is installed) so we can update it in our build scripts. If it's in the classpath this is trivial. But many developers don't put it in their classpath.

And same question for WebSphere too please.

thanks - dave

Comment: I have a feeling that there's a much better (and safer) way to achieve the same effect that you're aiming at. Can you provide more information about your scenario? what it is exactly that you're trying to achieve? simply put, a requirement to point to application server-specific JAR files usually implies that you're just about to shoot yourself in the foot. Help us help you!

Comment: @Isaac - The problem we have is people install our samples and they cannot compile them. So they call us, we explain that we don't know where their servlet.jar is. So they then set that in the project file we provided, and then it compiles and runs. We'd like to install so it just compiles eliminating that frustration. And of course we don't know if they have Tomcat (we handle that case), Weblogic, WebSphere, or something else.

Comment: If all you need is to compile against *standard* interfaces (such as the servlet API), your best bet (in my mind) would be to download the standard JAR files from the Oracle site and include those JARs in your distribution. Would that work?

Comment: @Isaac - unfortunately no, because there is no standard servlet.jar. That library is what provides the connection between the public servlet interface and a specific app server. So they must use the one for their app server.

Comment: Not sure what you're referring to, sorry. You had mentioned that the difficulties you encounter revolve around compilation. Assuming that the code only uses *standard* API's (such as `javax.servlet.*`) and not using any appserver-specific API's, then using the Oracle-published JAR files is definitely sufficient for compilation purposes. In other words, what we're missing from your scenario is this: why would your developer require appserver-specific JAR files for the purpose of *compilation*? are your developers going to compile code that uses appserver-specific facilities?

Comment: @Isaac - my worry is if I have the wrong servlet.jar file there, they will copy that over to their app-server's webapps folder and we've then created a worse problem - it all builds, but the servlet.jar won't talk to their app server. That's a harder problem to discover and debug.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18766/discussion-between-isaac-and-david-thielen)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you won't find the servlet.jar for both. Both servers are full blown Java EE servers. For websphere you can find the server apis somewhere(don't know the exact location). If you have the RAD it should show you the runtime libraries it is using. Have a look at those libs. You may find there what you are looking for.

Comment: This is for an installer we have with our samples for developers to install our samples. So we don't know what IDE they have, which app server they have, etc. I'm trying to come up with a way to probe to find what is there, and where, and then update the build.xml, project.ipr, etc. files we install.

Comment: @DavidThielen I do understand that part. However you should first search for what you are actually looking for. IIRC you won't find a servlet.jar for WebSphere, so you have to figure out which file you are searching for first.